# Problem Setting cookie parameter on remote server, NodeJs (backend) <-> React (front)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to have a parameter in the cookie called 'Myparameter' set by backend to different values.
Using Postman I can set cookies on the local environment and the remote environment, but using the page in the browser I can only use it locally, using remote backend server I can't update Myparameter on cookie.

Please check my backend:

```
var express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sessions = require('express-session');



var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({ origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://REMOTE_IP:3000'], credentials: true, exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"] }));
app.use(express.json());
//app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));





//const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const two_min_session = 1000 * 120;

app.use(session1 = sessions({
    name: "cookie_session1",
    secret: "fgydsanffdsafdsf456845dsfaf4651315641",
    cookie: {
        maxAge: two_min_session,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'strict',
        secure: false,
    },
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
}));

var one_more_cookie = function (req, res) {

    console.log(Date(), "Req", req.body, req.params, req.cookie);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'date, etag, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-credentials');
    res.cookie('refresh_token', 'refresh_token', {
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        path: '*/*'
    });
    res.status(200).json("Cookie Sent from Backend");

};
app.post('/api/cookie', cookieParser(), one_more_cookie);


app.post('/api/logincookie', cookieParser(), (req, res) => {
    console.log("Cookies", req.cookies);
    console.log(req.session, req.session);
    res.status(200).send({ 'Reading req': 'Reading req' });
});

app.post('/api/setcookie', cookieParser(), (req, res) => {
    console.log("Session Before", req.session);
    console.log("Cookies Before", req.cookies);
    req.session.Myparameter = "Check";
    console.log("Session After", req.session);
    console.log("Cookies After", req.cookies);
    res.status(200).json({ 'cookie': 'set' });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, function () { console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + port) });
```

Front End functions

```
const checkCookie = function () {

  const data = axios.post('http://REMOTE_IP:3000/api/logincookie',
    { withCredentials: true });
}


const setCookie = function () {
  const data = axios.post('http://REMOTE_IP:3000/api/setcookie',
    { withCredentials: true });

}

const getCookie = async () => {

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post('http://REMOTE_IP:3000/api/cookie',
      { withCredentials: true });

  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Using Inspect console, network tab I can see cookies, but only appear on Storage Cookie on Local env.
I already tried to copy directly postman code for fetch, but still not working.

Comment: If backend and server are not from same origin, cookie will not get set. Check if both req,res come from same origin?

Comment: Yes it works when backend and frontend runs on same server , but with postman works even if backend runs on different server than the one I use to make the request. I can't figure out how to make it work for frontend. Thanks for you answer in last case I will run both from same server.

Comment: if you are using react-app for frontend add a proxy in `package.json` ` "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"` and for `api` directly call using `/api/route`.

Comment: Thank you @MohammedShahed , I will try and then leave feedback.

Comment: Still not working with proxy on `package.json`